# How to make all non-date values null in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel doc where the users put dates and strings in the same column. I want to make every string object null and leave all the dates. How do I do this in pandas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to convert dates in a DataFrame is with [pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html), as mentioned by @Jeff, and it also handles numbers and timedeltas. Here is an example of using it:

```
# contents of Sheet1 of test.xlsx
x  y             date1      z     date2      date3
1  fum        6/1/2016      7  9/1/2015    string3
2  fo         6/2/2016  alpha   string0  10/1/2016
3  fi         6/3/2016      9  9/3/2015  10/2/2016
4  fee        6/4/2016     10   string1    string4
5  dumbledum  6/5/2016   beta   string2  10/3/2015
6  dumbledee  6/6/2016     12  9/4/2015    string5

import pandas as pd
xl = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df1 = df.convert_objects(convert_dates='coerce')
# 'coerce' required for conversion to NaT on error
df1
Out[7]: 
   x          y      date1      z      date2      date3
0  1        fum 2016-06-01      7 2015-09-01        NaT
1  2         fo 2016-06-02  alpha        NaT 2016-10-01
2  3         fi 2016-06-03      9 2015-09-03 2016-10-02
3  4        fee 2016-06-04     10        NaT        NaT
4  5  dumbledum 2016-06-05   beta        NaT 2015-10-03
5  6  dumbledee 2016-06-06     12 2015-09-04        NaT
```

Individual columns in a DataFrame can be converted using [pandas.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), as pointed out by @Jeff, and with [pandas.Series.map](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html), however neither are done in place. For example, with pandas.to_datetime:

```
import pandas as pd
xl2 = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df2 = xl2.parse("Sheet1")
for col in ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']:
    df2[col] = pd.to_datetime(df2[col],coerce=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
df2
Out[8]: 
   x          y      date1      z      date2      date3
0  1        fum 2016-06-01      7 2015-09-01        NaT
1  2         fo 2016-06-02  alpha        NaT 2016-10-01
2  3         fi 2016-06-03      9 2015-09-03 2016-10-02
3  4        fee 2016-06-04     10        NaT        NaT
4  5  dumbledum 2016-06-05   beta        NaT 2015-10-03
5  6  dumbledee 2016-06-06     12 2015-09-04        NaT
```

And using pandas.Series.map:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
xl3 = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df3 = xl3.parse("Sheet1")
for col in ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']:
    df3[col] = df3[col].map(lambda x: x if isinstance(x,(datetime.datetime)) else None)
df3
Out[9]: 
   x          y      date1      z      date2      date3
0  1        fum 2016-06-01      7 2015-09-01        NaT
1  2         fo 2016-06-02  alpha        NaT 2016-10-01
2  3         fi 2016-06-03      9 2015-09-03 2016-10-02
3  4        fee 2016-06-04     10        NaT        NaT
4  5  dumbledum 2016-06-05   beta        NaT 2015-10-03
5  6  dumbledee 2016-06-06     12 2015-09-04        NaT
```

An upfront way to convert dates in an excel doc is while parsing its sheets. This can be done using [pandas.ExcelFile.parse](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html)'s converters option with a function derived from [pandas.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) as the functions in the converters dict and enabling it with coerce=True to force errors to NaT. For example:

```
def converter(x):
    return pd.to_datetime(x,coerce=True,infer_datetime_format=True)
    # the following also works for this example
    # return pd.to_datetime(x,format='%d/%m/%Y',coerce=True)

converters={'date1': converter,'date2': converter, 'date3': converter}
xl4 = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
df4 = xl4.parse("Sheet1",converters=converters)
df4
Out[10]: 
   x          y      date1      z      date2      date3
0  1        fum 2016-06-01      7 2015-09-01        NaT
1  2         fo 2016-06-02  alpha        NaT 2016-10-01
2  3         fi 2016-06-03      9 2015-09-03 2016-10-02
3  4        fee 2016-06-04     10        NaT        NaT
4  5  dumbledum 2016-06-05   beta        NaT 2015-10-03
5  6  dumbledee 2016-06-06     12 2015-09-04        NaT
```

Comment: Rather than testing `type(x) == str`, it is preferable to do `isinstance(x, str)`. It can take a tuple of types, so your two tests can be consolidated to `isinstance(x, (str, unicode))` (or even `isinstance(x, basestring)`). In Python 3, you want `isinstance(x, (bytes, str))`.

Comment: @lvc: thank you for the information. My example has been changed to use isinstance, but its effective, simpler and addresses the question more directly to remove non-datetime objects from the date column.  Use of isinstance is supported by docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type, stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/… and stackoverflow.com/questions/2225038/

Comment: Thanks guys I adjusted my code. What if, I had many columns I wanted to do this to? Do I have to write a line for each column I want to check?

Comment: @AndyDo: You could use a for statement to loop over a list of columns.

Comment: @AndyDo: Good going.  I added a function to update datetime columns in a DataFrame based on certain criteria that enable it to identify candidate columns, determine if they need updating and then do it. For illustrative purposes the criteria used are (1) the column has dtype==numpy.object and it has at least one datetime.datetime element.

Comment: @TrisNefzger thank you for the update! I can't believe you wrote so much. Much appreciated!

Comment: @AndyDo: Its also possible to fix datetime columns during sheet parsing using the converters option with to_datetime functions. An example of this has been added to the answer.

Comment: these functions already exist: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects.html?highlight=convert_objects#pandas.DataFrame.convert_objects / alternatively http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html?highlight=to_datetime#pandas.to_datetime is quite general purpose

Comment: @Jeff: Thank you for the information. I have included an example of using DataFrame.convert_objects crediting you and upvoted your comment.

Comment: your comment in the answer is incorrect. nothing is ever done inplace, except if you specify ``inplace=True`` (e.g. you are simply displaying the result, it does NOT modify the existing df)

Comment: @Jeff: You are right and thank you for pointing it out. I would have sworn that I entered df again after convert_objects and it showed the changes but that did not happen when I tried it again this morning.  The comment has been removed and the result of convert_objects assigned to df1 whose contents are then shown.